# uk tourist visa

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

i applied for tourist visa a year ago and i got rejected , i got new passport and i travelled to bulgaria and now am tried to apply for uk again , they are asking me if i got refused from getting the visa before or not ?? , what should i answer them ?? , and i have an english family living there now but i didn't mention them in the first application last year , if i mention them now and make them send me invitation letter , will it make a problem ??

Answer (score 1):

You should always answer all questions truthfully. Never lie on any official forms. First of all, if they found out that you lied they can refuse a visa, or if they found out afterwards they could revoke any granted visa. Secondly, it may be a criminal offence resulting in arrest, detention (and/or a hefty fine), and deportation.

Depending on the type of visa being applied for, a letter of invitation may help. If you have family in the UK, then you have a valid reason to visit, after all. The thing they are most concerned about is whether or not you will leave at the end of your stay in the UK. If they think there is a chance that you might not leave, they will not grant a visa. So it would also help your application to mention any reasons you would have to need to leave the UK afterwards (job, family outside the UK, property owned outside the UK, etc.).

A travel history also helps - if you travelled to another country (e.g. Bulgaria) and you did not overstay your permission to remain there, that would be a point in your favour.